# Rounded shape div

Tags: css

I have a post div which sits on top of a weird background, and as you can see in this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5Qj0.png the text runs over the area I would want it to. I tried to use border-radius, but unfortunately that only modifies the look of the div, with the text still running over.

What I am trying to accomplish here is to create some sort of shape for the div's top right corner, in which the text will sit. I've tried to use some weird padding but that didn't do the trick either. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am so sorry, I didn't knew, I will remove the comment right way. Hope you are not offended :)

Comment: Oh my god I just noticed what I wrote, what I wanted to say is you're completely right, I'm not offended at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug, do not give a radius that is bigger than the half of the container's height. Only till [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/ZWwjg/1/), it is efficient enough.

However, as an alternative take a look into this [CSS Text Wrapper](http://www.csstextwrap.com/), this is exactly what you want.

Comment: The value for the radius wasn't bigger than half of the container's height. The div was looking the way I wanted it to, but the problem is that the text still ran over it, so padding was required in order to make it work. Thanks a lot for CSS Text Wrapper, though.

Answer (score 2):

it will work

```
 border-top-right-radius:400px;
```